# Adding two vectors using CUDA C, launching kernel

Tags: cuda

I have a homework to do in heterogeneous parallel programming. The code was written by the teaching staff and our duty is to just fill the areas marked by `//@@`. The code is supposed to add two vectors using CUDA C. I have tried the solution below, and although the program executes without errors, the feedback is saying the output of the code is not matching the expected result. Here is the code after I added what I believe is needed:

```
// MP 1
#include    <wb.h>

__global__ void vecAdd(float* in1, float* in2, float* out, int len) {
//@@ Insert code to implement vector addition here
int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
if (i < len ) out[i] = in1[i] + in2[i]; 
}



int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
wbArg_t args;
int inputLength;
float * hostInput1;
float * hostInput2;
float * hostOutput;
float * deviceInput1;
float * deviceInput2;
float * deviceOutput;
//@@ i added ######
int size = inputLength*sizeof(float);
//@@ ########
args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);

wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
hostInput1 = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &inputLength);
hostInput2 = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &inputLength);
hostOutput = (float *) malloc(inputLength * sizeof(float));

wbTime_stop(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");

wbLog(TRACE, "The input length is ", inputLength);

wbTime_start(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");
//@@ Allocate GPU memory here

cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceInput1 , size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceInput2 , size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceOutput , size);
wbTime_stop(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");

wbTime_start(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");
//@@ Copy memory to the GPU here
cudaMemcpy(deviceInput1, hostInput1, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(deviceInput2, hostInput2, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
wbTime_stop(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");

//@@ Initialize the grid and block dimensions here  
dim3 DimGrid((inputLength -1)/256 +1 , 1 , 1);
dim3 DimBlock(256 , 1, 1); 

wbTime_start(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");
//@@ Launch the GPU Kernel here     
vecAdd<<<DimGrid , DimBlock>>>(deviceInput1 , deviceInput2 , deviceOutput , inputLength); 
cudaThreadSynchronize();
wbTime_stop(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");

wbTime_start(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");
//@@ Copy the GPU memory back to the CPU here
cudaMemcpy(hostOutput, deviceOutput, size , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
wbTime_stop(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");

wbTime_start(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
//@@ Free the GPU memory here
free(deviceInput1);
free(deviceInput2);
free(deviceOutput);

wbTime_stop(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");

wbSolution(args, hostOutput, inputLength);

free(hostInput1);
free(hostInput2);
free(hostOutput);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it the coursera homework? :)

Comment: yes it is and the deadline is tonight

Comment: use `cudaFree()` for the GPU pointers, not `free()`

Comment: thank you talonmies . actually i had two errors , the first one is what you mentioned i have to put cudaFree instead of free , and the other one is where i placed int size as ahmad mentioned down

Answer (score 2):

Move your code down where the `inputLength` variable has got the proper value. Change this:

```
//@@ i added ######
int size = inputLength*sizeof(float);
//@@ ########
args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);

wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
hostInput1 = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &inputLength);
hostInput2 = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &inputLength);
hostOutput = (float *) malloc(inputLength * sizeof(float));
```

to this:

```
args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);

wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
hostInput1 = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &inputLength);
hostInput2 = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &inputLength);
hostOutput = (float *) malloc(inputLength * sizeof(float));

//@@ i added ######
int size = inputLength*sizeof(float);
//@@ ########
```

Moreover, do what suggested by talonmies in comments.

Comment: thank you ahmad . actually i had two errors , the first one is what talonmies mentioned i have to put cudaFree instead of free , and the other one is where i placed int size as you mentioned in your answer , i think that one way to express my thanks is to vote up for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

thank you both talonmies and ahmad they both helped to get the right answer which worked for me , and the complete answer (for who is interesting ) was the following :

```
// MP 1
#include    <wb.h>

__global__ void vecAdd(float* in1, float* in2, float* out, int len) {
int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
if (i < len ) out[i] = in1[i] + in2[i];
 }



int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
wbArg_t args;
int inputLength;
float * hostInput1;
float * hostInput2;
float * hostOutput;
float * deviceInput1;
float * deviceInput2;
float * deviceOutput;


args = wbArg_read(argc, argv);

wbTime_start(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");
hostInput1 = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 0), &inputLength);
hostInput2 = (float *) wbImport(wbArg_getInputFile(args, 1), &inputLength);
hostOutput = (float *) malloc(inputLength * sizeof(float));
int size = inputLength*sizeof(float);

wbTime_stop(Generic, "Importing data and creating memory on host");

wbLog(TRACE, "The input length is ", inputLength);

wbTime_start(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");


cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceInput1 , size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceInput2 , size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceOutput , size);
wbTime_stop(GPU, "Allocating GPU memory.");

wbTime_start(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");

cudaMemcpy(deviceInput1, hostInput1, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(deviceInput2, hostInput2, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
wbTime_stop(GPU, "Copying input memory to the GPU.");


dim3 DimGrid((inputLength -1)/256 +1 , 1 , 1);
dim3 DimBlock(256 , 1, 1); 

wbTime_start(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");
//@@ Launch the GPU Kernel 

vecAdd<<<DimGrid , DimBlock>>>(deviceInput1 , deviceInput2 , deviceOutput ,  inputLength);

cudaThreadSynchronize();
wbTime_stop(Compute, "Performing CUDA computation");

wbTime_start(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");
//@@ Copy the GPU memory back to the CPU 
cudaMemcpy(hostOutput, deviceOutput, size , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
wbTime_stop(Copy, "Copying output memory to the CPU");

wbTime_start(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");
//@@ Free the GPU memory 
cudaFree(deviceInput1);
cudaFree(deviceInput2);
cudaFree(deviceOutput);

wbTime_stop(GPU, "Freeing GPU Memory");

wbSolution(args, hostOutput, inputLength);

free(hostInput1);
free(hostInput2);
free(hostOutput);

return 0;
}
```